# Express restful mongodb api will not take post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been following a tutorial, and checked for typos but this code does not work.

When I send this from Postman as JSON, it does not do anything and just times out.

```
{
    "title": "my first post",
    "description": "test"
}
```

My route is this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Post = require('../models/Post');

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('We are on posts');
});

router.post('/', (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    });


    post.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});


module.exports = router;
```

This is the 'Post' module that I have set up:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema)
```

When data is posted, it is logged to the console which shows me that there is no issue between the api and Postman. The get method also works completely fine. I'm pulling my hair out trying to see what is wrong with the post method for this, can anybody help?

Comment: Is your DB connectivity working fine, Did you check if there are any issues over there ? Also in the `.catch` block you need to return the request - where you're just logging the `err`, Do you see any error over there ?

Comment: @srinivasy, It is connecting properly to the Database using the link given in atlas. Had it. Changed the err catch as well and it makes no difference

Comment: If the request is being properly printed in `POST` then there should be an error somewhere in the code, not sure where it's getting timeout, Where are you actually connecting to DB in code ?

Comment: Can you try like this and say what displays in console? `post.save().then(data => {console.log("SAVED");res.json(data);}).catch(err => {console.log("ERROR: ", err);res.status(500).send("error...");});`